# MongoDB cannot create UUID String in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Currently i have **reports** collection like below in database (simplified for clarity);

```json
{
    "_id": "33b4c208-4807-4004-ae55-d482266ee790",
    "reportTypeId": "RPT-100",
    "created": "2021-02-23T23:54:28.376+00:00",
    "userId": "cc278c75-9399-451e-a40d-64eb0d14625a",
    "rows": [
        {
            "row_field_1": "x",
            "row_field_2": "y",
            "row_field_3": "z"
        }
    ]
}
```

But we decide to seperate reports from rows so i created **reportRows** collection.

I write aggregate to transfer every rows of inside the report object to newly created reportRows collection.
But you already notice i dont have any **_id** field in report rows items so before i insert, i want to create an _id field with UUID String value.

I found documentation for UUID.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID/

The documentation says i can create random UUID using UUID() function but when i add _id field in the aggregation pipeline using **$set** or **$addFields** stages, MongoDB gives below error.

"MongoshInvalidInputError: Missing required argument."

And MongoDB Compass tool gives below warning for same pipeline.
"Stage must be properly formatted document"

// $set stage for adding (or setting) _id field for row

```json
{
    "$set": {
        "_id": UUID()
    }
}
```

How can i create or set _id field with random UUID String in aggregation pipeline?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you separating out the row?

Comment: Check your MongoDB version I think you are using 3.4 or earlier.

Comment: @Joe, I use $unwind stage in aggregation pipeline for destruct each rows item.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat db.version() function returns 4.4.1 as a version.